# Using Unleash Psyche repeatedly

Tags: pathfinder-2e, psychic-class

Can one use the Unleash Psyche action while it's still active to postpone the stupefication and loss of benefits?

> [**UNLEASH PSYCHE**](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=21)
>
> When one thins the barrier between their inner mind and the outer world, one can unleash true psychic power. However, the mind wasn't meant to tap its full strength for long, leading to backlash once your unleashed psyche ends.
>
> **UNLEASH PSYCHE** {Free Action}
> [Psychic]
> **Trigger** Your turn begins.
> **Requirements** You're in an encounter, you Cast a Spell on your previous turn, and you aren't stupefied.
>
> You call on the depths of your mind and let psychic power flood through. Your Psyche remains Unleashed for 2 rounds or until your fall unconscious, whichever comes first. You can't voluntarily quell your unleashed psyche. While your Psyche is Unleashed, the following effects occur.
>
> [...]
>
> After your unleashed psyche subsides, your mind must recover from the strain of channeling its full power. You can't use Unleash Psyche again for 2 rounds, and you're stupefied 1 for 2 rounds.

Comment: Player: "I unleash my psyche. Then, while my psyche is unleashed, I unleash it again!" GM: "How many leashes are on that psyche?" Player: "All of them!"

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan, Or: Player: "I let psychic power flood through", the actual wording...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Technically Maybe Yes But Definitely No

The wording of [Unleash Psyche](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=21) isn't direct in saying that it's a binary state; so, arguably, if your GM determines it isn't (which is a possible reading of RAW) then take your pick of either @brandon's answer or @Ifusaso's answer.

### RAW with a dose of Common Sense

However, a lot of the language of Unleash Psyche hints at being a binary state. For example:

> ...Your Psyche remains Unleashed... ...While your Psyche is Unleashed... ...After your unleashed psyche subsides...

@ikegami quotes some other abilities that hint at this:

> Your psyche must be unleashed to use abilities that have the [psyche trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=429)

> "Your psyche subsides as your power is expended." in [Psi Catastrophe](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3684)

Given these, it seems RAW that **your Psyche is in a binary state of Unleashed or Leashed** (or not-Unleashed). This also seems intuitive, as both @Ifusaso ("it's easy to think of it as a "state" that is "on or off"") and @brandon ("[stacking the ability is] Definitely not the most intuitive result based on the ability's name") hint at as well.

### If it's a binary state, it's either on or off

You can't turn a light switch more on than on - neither can your turn it more off than off. Neither can it be both on and off. That's how binary states work - and as the language of the ability plus the intuitive reading of the text hints, **you cannot stack Unleash Psyche, nor Unleash your Psyche when it is already Unleashed**.

### Be wary of too green of grass

If the above alone doesn't seem to be enough to make the case... it seems "too good to be true", as quoted in Ambiguous Rules (under [General Rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312)):

> "Sometimes a rule could be interpreted multiple ways. If one version is too good to be true, it probably is. If a rule seems to have wording with problematic repercussions or doesn’t work as intended, work with your group to find a good solution, rather than just playing with the rule as printed."

The Psychic is a cantrip focused spell caster - they will almost certainly be casting a spell every turn except in extreme circumstances. Being able to repeatedly Unleash Psyche is certainly way too good to be true - they'd always be in a state of Unleashed Psyche. Even per @Ifusaso's safer ruling, the Psychic would get an extra round of having Unleashed Psyche (just while simultaneously Stupefied 1). Both of these cases clearly seem to be too good to be true, as if that's what the designers wanted, there would be 100 more clears ways to say it - why place a penalty on Psyche ending if you can trivially ignore it? Given that there is an at least equally reasonable RAW reading that prevents this case, it really seems like the strongest case is that **you cannot Unleash your Psyche while your Psyche is Unleashed**.

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from justification of why being in this state for more than 2 rounds would be too strong to be true.

Comment: @brandon I can edit that in - are you looking for more than I mention in the comments on your answer?

Comment: Might make sense to go beyond what you put there, but whatever you feel is the most overpowered element of using Unleash Psyche each turn that makes it "too good to be true". Definitely could be a strong answer if there is some way to more deeply abuse this and disrupt the game.

Comment: @brandon Just the fact that it's clearly written to end, with penalties that would typically hamper a spellcaster, and describes its own benefits as powerful with a cost is enough for me to consider it "too good to be true" (not necessarily *overpowered*) that you can skirt the penalties and loss of benefits by re-activating it (a Free Action)

Comment: Good call bringing in the General rule, I forgot that text but definitely captures what my initial feeling was when reading it

Comment: Good call @Ifusaso - I've edited the language a bit to emphasize the skirting of the penalties seems to *good* (as opposed to strong). 

brandon - I couldn't think of an objective way to state that "pseudo-permanent Unleashed Psyche is overpowered" that didn't involve a multi-page dissertation on PF2e, so I just edited to focus on Ifusaso's point. Permanent access to something like [Fade Into Daydreams](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=1226) without a drawback seems very powerful, but it's hard to say that objectively, given Psychic's can already get it for most of a combat.

Comment: "Being able to repeatedly Unleash Psyche is certainly way too good to be true - they'd always be in a state of Unleashed Psyche." is really the part I struggle with here. Just stating it's 'clearly too good to be true' because it ignores a specific penalty (that can still happen with any disruption in the plan!) feels like a stretch, while difficulties in explaining why the benefits are too good seems like evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @brandon interrupting the plan basically requires a minimum of stunned or slowed 3 or a very specific reaction or really the caster to make the choice (since Shield exists, which requires a concentrate-triggered reaction that can disrupt the spell casting, while only taking one action - after which the Psychic can just cast another spell). In all, if that still doesn't seem "too good" to you in anyway (which is fine, it's an ultimately subjective line), that's okay - it's just one part of the evidence for a binary state UP, not the whole case.

Comment: @ESCE Fair points to make, but still not hitting why "pseudo-permanent Unleashed Psyche" is "certainly way too good to be true". I'd agree with "probably too good to be true", but this is too convinced of itself without some justification.

Answer (score 5):

### No (well, kind of but not indefinitely)

Applying a second instance of Unleash Psyche does not extend or affect the original instance of Unleash Psyche. Although it's easy to think of it as a "state" that is "on or off", it is still an [Effect](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=350) that follows the normal rules for [Duration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=351), meaning the first Unleash Psyche will end when it's time is up.

Technically, using Unleash Psyche on the second or third round give you the benefits for up to 2 more rounds (although you are still Stupefied from the first instance ending).

Comment: Re "*it's easy to think of it as a "state" that is "on or off"*", Well yeah, because this is how the rules refer to it. "Your Psyche remains Unleashed" in the quoted passage. "Your psyche must be unleashed to use abilities that have the psyche trait" in the description of the Psyche trait. "Your psyche subsides as your power is expended." in Psi Catastrophe. Respectively, these instruct you to set the state, test the state, and reset the state. You might have just convinced me the answer is "yes"!

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

Each turn you Cast a Spell you qualify on your next turn to Unleash Psyche as long as you aren't stupefied. There's no requirement similar to a barbarian's [rage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=3) that you aren't raging, so nothing prevents you from using this to keep your Psyche Unleashed by refreshing, "Your Psyche remains Unleashed for 2 rounds" each turn.

Definitely not the most intuitive result based on the ability's name, but staying in your psychic state until someone/something distracts you from your powers long enough seems to fit thematically with a psychic spellcaster letting loose.

### Is it Balanced?

Being able to effectively always have +2x spell level to standard damaging spells is certainly a strong effect when compared to something like a sorcerer's [Dangerous Sorcery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=603). That's double the damage bonus and it also could allow the psychic to use something like [Violent Unleash](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3667) or [Dark Persona's Presence](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3673) each turn.

However, there are some substantial limitations that drive that benefit into the realm of reasonable abilities like a barbarian's rage.

### Limitations

One limitation here is that you need to Cast a Spell each turn to keep this up, as every time you [start your turn](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=436) the number of rounds remaining on this effect you've created is reduced by 1. This specifically happens *before* you're able to take any reactions/free actions that trigger when your turn begins, so if you don't Unleash Psyche each turn the duration will run out and you'll become stupefied.

Another is in the psychic class, that they get far fewer spells than other equivalently-leveled full casters (1-2 of each level vs. 3-4). In exchange they do get stronger Cantrips, but this damage boost on a Cantrip really only helps bridge the gap rather than push the boundaries.

For each of the abilities that trigger on activation of Unleash Psyche there's substantial immediate drawbacks like becoming stunned 1 for Violent Unleash and that they don't distinguish between allies for the large area effects emanating from you (a 6 hp/lv cloth-wearing caster).

This also only functions *after* the first turn of combat, as the action requires that you've Cast a Spell on the previous turn. Not a huge penalty, but not being functional for 1 round out of every combat (at least) is a noticeable limitation to the benefits.

Finally, there's the basic penalty in the ability itself that failing to keep this chain going will render the psychic stupefied for 2 rounds. This is pretty devastating for a dedicated spellcaster, even if it can usually be avoided by just keeping the spells coming.

All-in-all the various limitations keep this ability reasonably balanced with other comparable options as defining features of other classes, and *definitely* not so powerful as to be clearly "too good to be true".

Comment: This really seems to run afoul of ["Sometimes a rule could be interpreted multiple ways. If one version is too good to be true, it probably is. If a rule seems to have wording with problematic repercussions or doesn’t work as intended, work with your group to find a good solution, rather than just playing with the rule as printed."](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312)

Comment: @ESCE I'm not at all convinced having this special ability last for even an entire combat would be "too good to be true". It's certainly a neat bonus, but do you have any specific issues with the benefits lasting that long?

Comment: the most basic reason is the: "When you cast a damaging spell, you gain a status bonus to its damage equal to double the spell's level. This applies only to spells that don't have a duration and that you cast using psychic spellcasting." This is a *significantly* better version of [Dangerous Sorcery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=603) since it applies to cantrips as well. That's on top of having near-permanent access to powerful abilities like [Calculate Threats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=1225) which is a phenomenal replacement for Raising A Shield.

Comment: Eh, it's better but Cantrips do less damage than at-level spells. More of a catch-up for psychics getting fewer proper spells that they pack more punch. And Calculate Threats is good, but a raised shield (or _shield_) can block damage.